# Can this be solved by FTC2?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Question: let $f$ be differentiable and defined everywhere: simplify

$$ \frac{d}{dx}  \left( \int_{0}^{x}   tf(x^2-t^2) \ dt\right)      $$
I'm confused becasuse if I attempt to use FTC2, it tells me that $$ xf(x^2-x^2) = xf(0)$$ which is obviously wrong. I may have violated the FTC2 definition; can anyone tell me how to use FTC2 to solve this problem.

Comment: the correct answer is $$ xf(x^2)$$

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) or substitute $u=x^2-t^2$.

Comment: Because $x$ also appears in the integrand, you have to use the full Leibniz rule for integration, which is in a sense an elaboration on the FTC2

Comment: @J.G. and then how to solve by ftc2?

Comment: @StephenDonovan , sir could you explain more explicit? I don’t understand how solve this question by leibniz rule

Comment: @DanielClarke Have you tried simplifying the integral that you get after applying the Leibniz rule? It's actually possible (and not very hard) to simplify it into terms of outputs of $f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $c$ is a constant, then we have the variants
$$
\frac{d}{dx}  \left( \int_{0}^{c}   tf(x^2-t^2) \ dt\right) = \int_{0}^{c}   tf'(x^2-t^2)\cdot2x \ dt
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dx}  \left( \int_{0}^{x}   tf(c^2-t^2) \ dt\right) = xf(c^2-x^2).
$$
It turns out (by the [Liebniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)) that when $x$ is in both places, the actual derivative is the sum of the two analogous answers:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}  \left( \int_{0}^{x}   tf(x^2-t^2) \ dt\right) = \int_{0}^{x}   tf'(x^2-t^2)\cdot2x \ dt + xf(x^2-x^2).
$$

Comment: But how do we do next step after getting this sum of the two analogues

Comment: @DanielClarke You can start with$$\int_0^xtf'(x^2-t^2)dt=\left[-\frac12f\left(x^2-t^2\right)\right]_0^x.$$

Comment: @J.G. Ohh I see thanks sir

Comment: @DanielClarke Please don't make assumptions about users' genders.

Comment: @GregMartin oops my bad, I just dont know how to call others with respect 